# Create a Drive Api Service with an API Key C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, drive

I am making an application that uses a API key to authenticate and use the Drive API service. I am not using other methods to authenticate.
This is my code.

```
        var bcs = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
        bcs.ApiKey = "38a0f7d505fe18fec64fbf343ecaaaf310dbd744";
        bcs.ApplicationName = "sampleApp";
        var service = new DriveService(bcs);
        // Define parameters of request.
        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = 10;
        listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

        // List files.
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
            .Files;
        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

It doesn't work. How do I use an API key to authenticate?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm a bit late to answer this, but this can help future people. If the folder (I guess your are trying to get the files in a folder) is set to public then you don’t need to be authenticated. You can access it using a public API key.
The solution was almost there, it only needed the property .Q set to the folder ID:

```
    Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer bcs = new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer();
    bcs.ApiKey = "38a0f7d505fe18fec64fbf343ecaaaf310dbd744";
    bcs.ApplicationName = "sampleApp";

    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService service = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(bcs);

    // Define parameters of request.
    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();

    string folderID = "1234567"; //Change this for your folder ID.
    listRequest.Q = "'" + folderID + "' in parents";
    listRequest.PageSize = 10;
    listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

    // List files.
    IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute().Files;
    Console.WriteLine("Files:");
    if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", file.Name, file.Id);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
    }
    Console.Read();
```

This way it finds all files located directly in the folder whose ID is 1234567.
'Q' property can be used for more things, for example to search for folders using the folder-specific MIME type. In this case it would be something like:

```
listRequest.Q = "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
```

To know more about how we could use 'Q' property: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

And here there are nice links on how to create services Public and Private and then how to get files from folders, and how to solve the case in which you have more than 1000 files in a folder:

- Services: http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/
- Get Files: http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c/

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting the below error :

The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Forbidden. The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.

Comment: While this works for download really well.. this just doesnt work for getting the list of the folders/files..

Answer (score 0):

Your application must use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

All requests to the Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user.

The details of the authorization process, or "flow," for OAuth 2.0 vary somewhat depending on what kind of application you're writing. The following general process applies to all application types:

- When you create your application, you register it using the [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
- Activate the Drive API in the Google API Console. (If the API isn't listed in the API Console, then skip this step.)
- When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular **scope** of access.
- Google displays a **consent screen** to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
- If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived **access token**.
- Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
- If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

Some flows include additional steps, such as using **refresh tokens** to acquire new access tokens. For detailed information about flows for various types of applications, see Google's [OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Here's the OAuth 2.0 scope information for the Drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#what_scope_or_scopes_does_my_app_need